# putStr inside IO () function

Tags: haskell, io, monads

How to call IO () function inside another IO () function? I want to print to standard output then call function to do the same.

For example,

```
p :: String -> IO ()
p [x] = putStr x
p xs = q xs

q :: String -> IO ()
q (x:xs) = putStr x ++ p xs
```

Comment: `p [x] = putStr x` is wrong. `x` is a char, not string. `putStr x ++ p xs` is wrong, you can't add 2 `IO()`. Use `putChar x >> p xs`.

Comment: Also you are missing the case of empty lists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first problem is with typing

```
p [x] = putStr x
{- putStr :: String -> IO ()
   x      :: Char, not a String
-}
```

and

```
q (x:xs) = putStr x ++ p xs
{- (++)     :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
   putStr x :: IO (), not a list of anything.
-}
```

---

Let's look at `q` first, since it follows from `p`. You're breaking it down into characters, so you should use `putChar` rather than `putStr`

Also we're looking at sequencing actions, so we should either use `(>>)` or `(>>=)` depending on whether or not you need the result. In this case the result is a value of the unit type (`()`) which is a useless result and safe to ignore.

```
q :: String -> IO ()
q (x:xs) = putChar x >> p xs
{- or using `do` notation:
     q (x:xs) = do
       putChar x
       p xs
-}
```

`p` can be changed likewise to use `putChar` rather than `putStr`

```
p :: String -> IO ()
p [x] = putChar x
p xs  = q xs
```

though be aware that you haven't matched an empty list on either `p` or `q`.

---

About this time you should notice that substituting `putChar` for `putStr` just so you can break strings down to Chars is kind of backward thinking. `p = putStr` and you're done. However, if you're committed to this backward thinking:

```
import Control.Monad (foldM_, mapM_)

p = foldM_ (\_ x -> putChar x) ()
-- or
p = foldM_ ((putChar .) . flip const) ()
-- or
p = mapM_ putChar
```

Comment: That `do` notation would desugar with `(>>)`, not bind.